# Flash action script tweenlite 1084

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm a beginner in flash i got an error in actions script 3.0

I'm using tween lite

I got the error 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before comma.

its about this line

```
TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:141,35, y:balk_mc.y});
```

And it says line 10 and 16

The whole code im using is:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.greensock.*;
stop();



button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1_clicked);
function button1_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("page1");
    TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:141,35, y:balk_mc.y});
}

button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button2_clicked);
function button2_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("page2");
    TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:330,6, y:balk_mc.y});
}

button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button3_clicked);
function button3_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("page3");
    TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:551, y:balk_mc.y});
    var number:Number = 1;

next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);

checkNumber();
function nextImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
//trace("next button geklikt!");
number++;
loader.source = "images/tommorrowland"+number+".png";
checkNumber();
}

previous_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previousImage);

function previousImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
//trace("previous button geklikt!");
number--;
loader.source = "images/tommorrowland"+number+".png";
checkNumber();
}

function checkNumber():void {
next_btn.visible = true;
previous_btn.visible = true;
if(number == 4){
    next_btn.visible = false;
}
if(number == 1){
    previous_btn.visible = false;
}

}
}

button4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button4_clicked);
function button4_clicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop("page4");
    TweenLite.to(balk_mc, 1, {x:551, y:balk_mc.y});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `141,35` instead of `141.35`. It's a typing error. Numbers in coding languages are written with a point. Same goes to `330,6` you've got in your code.